# Node.js open package multiple different chrome profiles

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, npm, command-line-interface

I'm trying to open multiple chrome profiles from my command line interface which I coded in node.js. However, when I use the open package, the links which should be opened in different chrome profiles always get opened in the same profile (in multiple tabs but still the same profile). I want to open them in other chrome profiles tho.

```
const opn = require('open');

opn('https://www.google.com', {app: ['C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe', '--profile-directory="Default"']});

opn('https://www.snipes.com', {app: ['C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe', '--profile-directory="Profile 2"']});
```